# How to get the sha256 of a 'binary' array in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sha256, hashlib, binascii

given the following Python code:

```
bits = [0]*256  # for simplicity (actually it's more like (0|1)^n)
binstr = ""  # make string containing all 'bits'
for el in bits:
    binstr += str(el)
```

how can I get the binary string of the sha256 of the bits/ binstr. (Meaning how to achieve binary(sha256(bits)).
I got stuck when using something like:

```
import hashlib
import binascii

hexstr = "{0:0>4X}".format(int(binstr, 2))
data = binascii.a2b_hex(hexstr)
print(data)
> b'\x00\x00'
output = hashlib.sha256(data).hexdigest()
print(output)
> 96a296d224f285c67bee93c30f8a309157f0daa35dc5b87e410b78630a09cfc7
```

Maybe you could help me to find my mistakes.

Comment: What happens when you run your code?

Comment: @itprorh66 i add the print results

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a library function to do it but you can convert the hex string to an int, then the int to a bin.

```
bin(int(hashlib.sha256("whatever you want to hash").hexdigest(), 16))
```

Comment: sure, but this "whatever you want to hash" is a string, I only have an array of bits (which I can concatenate to a string of bits if necessary). So I want the hash not to using the string, like sha("01010") i want something like sha(01010).